# Bit width calculation

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to understand "`bit overflow`" so I made a simple example.

As I understand, hex value `'hFF` can convert to `7'b11111111`

So I implement to check with `$display("%b" , {7'hff});`

But, I got the below warning message.

```
$display("%b" , {7'hff}); 
                         |
xmvlog: *W,INTOVF (testbench.sv,18|25): bit overflow during conversion from text [2.5(IEEE)] (7 bits).
```

How do I calculate the bit width, and why does the `bit overflow` warning message happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "bit overflow" message happens because you specified 7 as the bit width, but your numeric literal (`ff`) requires 8 bits.

> As I understand, hex value `'hFF` can convert to `7'b11111111`

No, `'hFF` converts to `8'b11111111`.  If you count the number of `1`'s, you have 8.

Verilog syntax supports the underline character as a visual separator to make it easier to understand numeric literals with several digits.  For example, you could write the number as `'b1111_1111`.  That makes it easier to see that there are 8 `1`'s.

To avoid the warning, use `8'hff`.

The maximum 7-bit hex value is `7'h7f`.